# Get the number of tokens using a specific parsing character

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy string:

> my first name is Pearly, and my surname is Spencer

Is there an out-of-the-box way in Stata (mata included) to get the number of tokens based on a *user-specified* parsing character? In this particular example, two tokens separated by a comma.

Solutions like the macro extended function for parsing `word count` use a space
and I would like to avoid  writing a program for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of tokens is the number of parsing characters PLUS 1.

That being so, using commas as example parsing characters,

```
gen ntokens = 1 + strlen(strvar) - strlen(subinstr(strvar, ",", "", .))
```

See https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0056 for a write-up of this simple trick.