# Tokenize parse option

Tags: stata

Consider a slightly different toy example from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062401/get-the-number-of-tokens-using-a-specific-parsing-character):

```
. local string my first name is Pearly,, and my surname is Spencer

. tokenize "`string'", parse(",,")

. display "`1'"
my first name is Pearly

. display "`2'"
,

. display "`3'"
,

. display "`4'"
and my surname is Spencer
```

I have two questions:

1. Does `tokenize` work as expected in this case? I thought local macro 
   `2` should be `,,` instead of `,` while local macro `3` contain the rest of the string (and local macro `4` be empty).
2. Is there a way to force `tokenize` to respect the double comma as a parsing
   character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tokenize` -- and `gettoken` too -- won't, from what I can see, accept ***repeated*** characters such as `,,` as a ***composite*** parsing character. `,,` is not illegal as a specification of parsing characters, but is just understood as meaning that `,` and `,` are acceptable parsing characters. The repetition in practice is ignored, just as adding "My name is Pearly" after "My name is Pearly" doesn't add information in a conversation.

To back up: know that without other instructions (such as might be given by a `syntax` command) Stata will parse a string according to spaces, except that double quotes (or compound double quotes) bind harder than spaces separate.

`tokenize` -- and `gettoken` too -- will accept multiple parse characters *pchars* and the help for `tokenize` gives an example with space and `+` sign. (It's much more common, in my experience, to want to use space and comma `,` when the syntax for a command is not quite what `syntax` parses completely.)

A difference between space and the other parsing characters is that spaces are discarded but other parsing characters are not discarded. The rationale here is that those characters often have meaning you might want to take forward. Thus in setting up syntax for a command option, you might want to allow something like     `myoption(` *varname* [`,` *suboptions*]`)`
and so whether a comma is present and other stuff follows is important for later code.

With composite characters, so that you are looking for say `,,` as separators I think you'd need to loop around using `substr()` or an equivalent. In practice an easier work-around might be first to replace your composite characters with some neutral single character and then apply `tokenize`. That could need to rely on knowing that that neutral character should not occur otherwise. Thus I often use `@` as a character  placeholder because I know that it will not occur as part of variable or scalar names and it's not part of function names or an operator.

For what it's worth, I note that in first writing `split` I allowed composite characters as separators. As I recall, a trigger to that was a question on Statalist which was about data for legal cases with multiple variations on `VS` (versus) to indicate which party was which. This example survives into the help for the official command.

On what is a "serious" bug, much depends on judgment. I think a programmer would just discover on trying it out that composite characters don't work as desired with `tokenize` in cases like yours.